# Get dependent countries from same dropdown

Tags: html, jquery

If we have one dropdown and when we select any item, we need to fetch records having the dependid attribute till dependid is not equal to 0. Below is the code snippet.

```html
<select class="form-control dropdownlist" id="Location">
  <option value="67" dependid="17">Amsterdam</option>
  <option value="1" dependid="0">APAC</option>
  <option value="20" dependid="3">Argentina</option>
  <option value="23" dependid="4">Arizona</option>
  <option value="40" dependid="26">Atlanta</option>
  <option value="47" dependid="31">Austin</option>
  <option value="5" dependid="1">Australia</option>
  <option value="12" dependid="2">Austria</option>
  <option value="54" dependid="8">Bangalore</option>
  <option value="61" dependid="74">Bangkok</option>
  <option value="69" dependid="19">Brighton</option>
  <option value="71" dependid="20">Buenos Aires</option>
  <option value="24" dependid="4">California</option>
  <option value="21" dependid="3">Canada</option>
  <option value="25" dependid="4">Canada - Cloud5</option>
  <option value="41" dependid="27">Chicago</option>
  <option value="6" dependid="1">China</option>
  <option value="48" dependid="31">Dallas</option>
  <option value="2" dependid="0">EMEA</option>
  <option value="75" dependid="4">Florida</option>
  <option value="15" dependid="2">France</option>
  <option value="63" dependid="13">Frankfurt</option>
  <option value="26" dependid="4">Georgia</option>
  <option value="13" dependid="2">Germany</option>
  <option value="55" dependid="8">Gurgaon</option>
  <option value="7" dependid="1">Hong Kong</option>
  <option value="27" dependid="4">Illinois</option>
  <option value="8" dependid="1">India</option>
  <option value="16" dependid="2">Italy</option>
  <option value="37" dependid="75">Jacksonville</option>
  <option value="9" dependid="1">Japan</option>
  <option value="3" dependid="0">LACC</option>
  <option value="42" dependid="76">Las Vegas</option>
  <option value="70" dependid="19">London</option>
  <option value="35" dependid="24">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="64" dependid="14">Madrid</option>
  <option value="22" dependid="3">Mexico</option>
  <option value="73" dependid="22">Mexico City</option>
  <option value="56" dependid="8">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="46" dependid="30">Nashville</option>
  <option value="17" dependid="2">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="76" dependid="4">Nevada</option>
  <option value="28" dependid="4">New York</option>
  <option value="43" dependid="28">New York</option>
  <option value="38" dependid="75">Orlando</option>
  <option value="57" dependid="9">Osaka</option>
  <option value="29" dependid="4">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="44" dependid="29">Philadelphia</option>
  <option value="34" dependid="23">Phoenix</option>
  <option value="66" dependid="16">Rome</option>
  <option value="65" dependid="15">Rueil Malmaison</option>
  <option value="36" dependid="25">Saint John</option>
  <option value="49" dependid="32">Salt Lake City</option>
  <option value="50" dependid="33">Seattle</option>
  <option value="52" dependid="6">Shanghai</option>
  <option value="10" dependid="1">Singapore</option>
  <option value="59" dependid="10">Singapore</option>
  <option value="14" dependid="2">Spain </option>
  <option value="68" dependid="18">Stockholm</option>
  <option value="39" dependid="75">Sunrise</option>
  <option value="18" dependid="2">Sweden/Finland</option>
  <option value="51" dependid="5">Sydney</option>
  <option value="53" dependid="7">Taikoo Shing</option>
  <option value="60" dependid="11">Taipei</option>
  <option value="11" dependid="1">Taiwan</option>
  <option value="30" dependid="4">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="31" dependid="4">Texas</option>
  <option value="74" dependid="1">Thailand</option>
  <option value="58" dependid="9">Tokyo</option>
  <option value="72" dependid="21">Toronto</option>
  <option value="19" dependid="2">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="4" dependid="0">US</option>
  <option value="32" dependid="4">Utah</option>
  <option value="62" dependid="12">Vienna</option>
  <option value="33" dependid="4">Washington</option>
  <option value="45" dependid="29">Wilkes-Barre</option>
</select>
```

[jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2b3rjytc/1/)

For example if I select item having value 1 (Item : APAC) associated countries will be
Australia, China, Hong Kong,India, Japan, Singapore, Taiwan, Thailand
Australia >> value 5 >> check associated items further >>
same for china, Hong Kong,India, Japan, Singapore, Taiwan, Thailand
*Please help*

Comment: Please make an attempt first and provide what you have done first, also if there is a way to reword this, please do so, as it is very confusing what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: @Jacob thanks for replying suppose I have selected item APAC then we have to fetch all those records which contains APAC value (1) using dependid attribute

Comment: You should consider [Using Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store that additional value `<option value="67" data-dependid="17">Amsterdam</option>`

Comment: While you are not asking for suggestions to improve usability of this component, it might help you find an easier technical solution, so I’m asking anyway: You are mixing countries, states and economical groupings all in one list. Are your users expert enough to easily navigate between these concepts and find the entries in one long list?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the attribute selector for this `element[attribute="value"]` and the value of the `select` element after it changed (`this` is here the changed `select` element):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('option[dependid="' + this.value + '"]');
```

Then you just need to loop over the selected options and do what ever you want with them, for example output them in a list (before that reset the list with `result_list.innerHTML = '';`).

**Working example:**

```js
const select_element = document.querySelector('#Location');
const result_list = document.querySelector('#result-list');

select_element.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const dependent_options = document.querySelectorAll('option[dependid="' + this.value + '"]');
  result_list.innerHTML = '';
  
  for (i = 0; i < dependent_options.length; i++) {
    let list_item = document.createElement('LI');
    list_item.textContent = dependent_options[i].textContent;
    result_list.appendChild(list_item);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="result-list"></ul>

<select class="form-control dropdownlist" id="Location">
  <option value="67" dependid="17">Amsterdam</option>
  <option value="1" dependid="0">APAC</option>
  <option value="20" dependid="3">Argentina</option>
  <option value="23" dependid="4">Arizona</option>
  <option value="40" dependid="26">Atlanta</option>
  <option value="47" dependid="31">Austin</option>
  <option value="5" dependid="1">Australia</option>
  <option value="12" dependid="2">Austria</option>
  <option value="54" dependid="8">Bangalore</option>
  <option value="61" dependid="74">Bangkok</option>
  <option value="69" dependid="19">Brighton</option>
  <option value="71" dependid="20">Buenos Aires</option>
  <option value="24" dependid="4">California</option>
  <option value="21" dependid="3">Canada</option>
  <option value="25" dependid="4">Canada - Cloud5</option>
  <option value="41" dependid="27">Chicago</option>
  <option value="6" dependid="1">China</option>
  <option value="48" dependid="31">Dallas</option>
  <option value="2" dependid="0">EMEA</option>
  <option value="75" dependid="4">Florida</option>
  <option value="15" dependid="2">France</option>
  <option value="63" dependid="13">Frankfurt</option>
  <option value="26" dependid="4">Georgia</option>
  <option value="13" dependid="2">Germany</option>
  <option value="55" dependid="8">Gurgaon</option>
  <option value="7" dependid="1">Hong Kong</option>
  <option value="27" dependid="4">Illinois</option>
  <option value="8" dependid="1">India</option>
  <option value="16" dependid="2">Italy</option>
  <option value="37" dependid="75">Jacksonville</option>
  <option value="9" dependid="1">Japan</option>
  <option value="3" dependid="0">LACC</option>
  <option value="42" dependid="76">Las Vegas</option>
  <option value="70" dependid="19">London</option>
  <option value="35" dependid="24">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="64" dependid="14">Madrid</option>
  <option value="22" dependid="3">Mexico</option>
  <option value="73" dependid="22">Mexico City</option>
  <option value="56" dependid="8">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="46" dependid="30">Nashville</option>
  <option value="17" dependid="2">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="76" dependid="4">Nevada</option>
  <option value="28" dependid="4">New York</option>
  <option value="43" dependid="28">New York</option>
  <option value="38" dependid="75">Orlando</option>
  <option value="57" dependid="9">Osaka</option>
  <option value="29" dependid="4">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="44" dependid="29">Philadelphia</option>
  <option value="34" dependid="23">Phoenix</option>
  <option value="66" dependid="16">Rome</option>
  <option value="65" dependid="15">Rueil Malmaison</option>
  <option value="36" dependid="25">Saint John</option>
  <option value="49" dependid="32">Salt Lake City</option>
  <option value="50" dependid="33">Seattle</option>
  <option value="52" dependid="6">Shanghai</option>
  <option value="10" dependid="1">Singapore</option>
  <option value="59" dependid="10">Singapore</option>
  <option value="14" dependid="2">Spain </option>
  <option value="68" dependid="18">Stockholm</option>
  <option value="39" dependid="75">Sunrise</option>
  <option value="18" dependid="2">Sweden/Finland</option>
  <option value="51" dependid="5">Sydney</option>
  <option value="53" dependid="7">Taikoo Shing</option>
  <option value="60" dependid="11">Taipei</option>
  <option value="11" dependid="1">Taiwan</option>
  <option value="30" dependid="4">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="31" dependid="4">Texas</option>
  <option value="74" dependid="1">Thailand</option>
  <option value="58" dependid="9">Tokyo</option>
  <option value="72" dependid="21">Toronto</option>
  <option value="19" dependid="2">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="4" dependid="0">US</option>
  <option value="32" dependid="4">Utah</option>
  <option value="62" dependid="12">Vienna</option>
  <option value="33" dependid="4">Washington</option>
  <option value="45" dependid="29">Wilkes-Barre</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is fine @biberman or if we have to contains further items on the basis of that dependent Id values then how we can get those : For example if I select item having value 1 (Item : APAC) associated countries will be Australia, China, Hong Kong,India, Japan, Singapore, Taiwan, Thailand Australia >> value 5 >> check associated items further >> same for china, Hong Kong,India, Japan, Singapore, Taiwan, Thailand any idea

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a solution using jquery. You have to obtain the options which dependid equals to the category selected. Then you have to iterate over these items.

```js
$("#Location").change(function () {                            
   var category= $(this).val();
   console.log(category);
   console.log("Dependant items: ");
   var items = $("option[dependid='" + category + "']");
   
   $.each( items, function( key, value ) {
    console.log($(value).text());
   });
});
```

**Working example:**

```js
$("#Location").change(function () {                            
   var category= $(this).val();
   console.log(category);
   console.log("Dependant items: ");
   var items = $("option[dependid='" + category + "']");
   
   $.each( items, function( key, value ) {
    console.log($(value).text());
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="result-list"></ul>

<select class="form-control dropdownlist" id="Location">
  <option value="67" dependid="17">Amsterdam</option>
  <option value="1" dependid="0">APAC</option>
  <option value="20" dependid="3">Argentina</option>
  <option value="23" dependid="4">Arizona</option>
  <option value="40" dependid="26">Atlanta</option>
  <option value="47" dependid="31">Austin</option>
  <option value="5" dependid="1">Australia</option>
  <option value="12" dependid="2">Austria</option>
  <option value="54" dependid="8">Bangalore</option>
  <option value="61" dependid="74">Bangkok</option>
  <option value="69" dependid="19">Brighton</option>
  <option value="71" dependid="20">Buenos Aires</option>
  <option value="24" dependid="4">California</option>
  <option value="21" dependid="3">Canada</option>
  <option value="25" dependid="4">Canada - Cloud5</option>
  <option value="41" dependid="27">Chicago</option>
  <option value="6" dependid="1">China</option>
  <option value="48" dependid="31">Dallas</option>
  <option value="2" dependid="0">EMEA</option>
  <option value="75" dependid="4">Florida</option>
  <option value="15" dependid="2">France</option>
  <option value="63" dependid="13">Frankfurt</option>
  <option value="26" dependid="4">Georgia</option>
  <option value="13" dependid="2">Germany</option>
  <option value="55" dependid="8">Gurgaon</option>
  <option value="7" dependid="1">Hong Kong</option>
  <option value="27" dependid="4">Illinois</option>
  <option value="8" dependid="1">India</option>
  <option value="16" dependid="2">Italy</option>
  <option value="37" dependid="75">Jacksonville</option>
  <option value="9" dependid="1">Japan</option>
  <option value="3" dependid="0">LACC</option>
  <option value="42" dependid="76">Las Vegas</option>
  <option value="70" dependid="19">London</option>
  <option value="35" dependid="24">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="64" dependid="14">Madrid</option>
  <option value="22" dependid="3">Mexico</option>
  <option value="73" dependid="22">Mexico City</option>
  <option value="56" dependid="8">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="46" dependid="30">Nashville</option>
  <option value="17" dependid="2">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="76" dependid="4">Nevada</option>
  <option value="28" dependid="4">New York</option>
  <option value="43" dependid="28">New York</option>
  <option value="38" dependid="75">Orlando</option>
  <option value="57" dependid="9">Osaka</option>
  <option value="29" dependid="4">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="44" dependid="29">Philadelphia</option>
  <option value="34" dependid="23">Phoenix</option>
  <option value="66" dependid="16">Rome</option>
  <option value="65" dependid="15">Rueil Malmaison</option>
  <option value="36" dependid="25">Saint John</option>
  <option value="49" dependid="32">Salt Lake City</option>
  <option value="50" dependid="33">Seattle</option>
  <option value="52" dependid="6">Shanghai</option>
  <option value="10" dependid="1">Singapore</option>
  <option value="59" dependid="10">Singapore</option>
  <option value="14" dependid="2">Spain </option>
  <option value="68" dependid="18">Stockholm</option>
  <option value="39" dependid="75">Sunrise</option>
  <option value="18" dependid="2">Sweden/Finland</option>
  <option value="51" dependid="5">Sydney</option>
  <option value="53" dependid="7">Taikoo Shing</option>
  <option value="60" dependid="11">Taipei</option>
  <option value="11" dependid="1">Taiwan</option>
  <option value="30" dependid="4">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="31" dependid="4">Texas</option>
  <option value="74" dependid="1">Thailand</option>
  <option value="58" dependid="9">Tokyo</option>
  <option value="72" dependid="21">Toronto</option>
  <option value="19" dependid="2">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="4" dependid="0">US</option>
  <option value="32" dependid="4">Utah</option>
  <option value="62" dependid="12">Vienna</option>
  <option value="33" dependid="4">Washington</option>
  <option value="45" dependid="29">Wilkes-Barre</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("change","#Location",function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var arrayWithDependId=[];
    $("#Location").find("option").each(function(){
        var dependId = $(this).attr("dependid");
        if(dependId==val){
            arrayWithDependId.push($(this).text());
        }       
    });
    console.log(arrayWithDependId); 
});
```